# Listing objects from database to html page via springboot and thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Springs MVC framework in my project with thymeleaf, I have searched online for tutorials in how to show a list of objects from the database on a html page via a table, with no success. If you guys have any tutorials you would recommend for this please let me know, or if you know how to implement what I am trying to do

Here is my controller code which doesn't do anything as it is not correct:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
@Autowired
TeamRepository teamRepository;
  @RequestMapping(value="/showteams", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public Set<Team> teams()
   {       
       Set<Team> teams = (Set<Team>) teamRepository.findAll();         
       return teams;
   }
```

My repository code:

```
@Repository
public interface TeamRepository extends JpaRepository<Team, Long> {     
    Team findByTeamName(String teamname);
    Set<Team> listAllTeams();    
}
```

Heres my team entity code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team")   
public class Team implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String teamName;
    private int leaguePosition;
    public String teamAddress;
    public String level;

    @OneToOne
    private Manager manager;

    @OneToOne
    private Physio physio;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     public Set<CoachingStaff> coachingStaff;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     public Set<Player> players;

    //getter setter constructors

}
```

And my html code:

```
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">

 <div th:if="$(not #lists.isEmpty(teams))">

    <h2> Teams List </h2>

    <table class = "table table-striped">       
    <tr>
    <th> Team Name </th>
    </tr>       
    <tr th:each="team : ${teams]">
    <td th:text="${team.teamName}"></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
 </div>        
 </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

The error i get when running my app:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-01-15 15:55:58.377 ERROR 7584 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'teamRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teamRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property listAllTeams found for type Team!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at com.FYP.Club.ClubApplication.main(ClubApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teamRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property listAllTeams found for type Team!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property listAllTeams found for type Team!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:247) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:378) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:64) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:213) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What have you tested and what stack trace errors you got?

Comment: @MikeTung I updated my question there with the trace errors, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First in your `HomeController` you return a `Set<Team>` and not a thymeleaf view. You should add your set to a model to use it in your view.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/showteams", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String teams()
{
   Set<Team> teams = (Set<Team>) teamRepository.findAll();
   model.addAttribute("teams", teams);
   return "teams";//here your name of your view (html)
}
```

The second problem is your html. There is an error in

```
<tr th:each="team : ${teams]">
```

change it to:

```
<tr th:each="team : ${teams}">
```

The third issue I see is your Repository annotation. Normally you dont need to specifiy your repository. So delete the annotation.

For your exception: You need to specify a custom `@Query()` for your `listAllTeams()` method. But if you want to find all teams the JPARepository which you extended has already a method for that `findAll()`. Use this and delete the `Set<Team> listAllTeams();` entry.

Answer (score 0):

Hi change your repository add  @Qualifier("teamRepository") like below, hope it will work.

```
@Qualifier("teamRepository")
@Repository
public interface TeamRepository extends JpaRepository<Team, Long> {     
    Team findByTeamName(String teamname);
    Set<Team> listAllTeams();    
}
```

Comment: why should `@Qualifier("teamRepository")` help? Do you have any explanation for that.

Comment: in controller he is using "TeamRepository teamRepository"; and i found the error like - Error creating bean with name 'teamRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property listAllTeams found for type Team!

Comment: The error `No property listAllTeams found for type Team!` occours because there is no property set in the entity team. The @Qualifier annotation is used to resolve the autowiring conflict, when there are multiple beans of same type.

The @Qualifier annotation can be used on any class annotated with @Component or on method annotated with @Bean. This annotation can also be applied on constructor arguments or method parameters.